# WSO2 Stream Processor MySQL CDC connection error by charset class not found

Tags: wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am reading and doing WSO2 Stream Processor 4.4.0 Tutorial from its tutorial (Capturing+Changes+from+Data+Stores) step by step.

But unfortunately WSO2SP could not get snapshot from database with these logs:

```
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.siddhi.editor.core.internal.StartupComponent} - Editor Started on : http://192.168.10.101:9390/editor
[2020-01-18 16:30:05,947]  INFO {org.wso2.msf4j.internal.MicroservicesServerSC} - All microservices are available
[2020-01-18 16:30:05,947]  INFO {org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.listener.ServerConnectorBootstrap$HttpServerConnector} - HTTP(S) Interface starting on host 0.0.0.0 and port 9743
[2020-01-18 16:30:05,962]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.idp.client.core.utils.IdPServiceUtils} - IdP client of type 'local' is started.
[2020-01-18 16:30:05,962]  INFO {org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.listener.ServerConnectorBootstrap$HttpServerConnector} - HTTP(S) Interface starting on host 0.0.0.0 and port 9390
[2020-01-18 16:30:06,072]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiverServiceComponent} - org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.Service Component is activated
[2020-01-18 16:30:06,087]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.internal.ThriftDataReceiverDS} - Service Component is activated
[2020-01-18 16:30:06,118]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.CarbonStartupHandler} - WSO2 Stream Processor started in 15.831 sec
[2020-01-18 18:16:53,612]  INFO {org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverterConfig} - JsonConverterConfig values:
        converter.type = key
        schemas.cache.size = 1000
        schemas.enable = true


[2020-01-18 18:16:53,628]  INFO {io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine$EmbeddedConfig} - EmbeddedConfig values:
        access.control.allow.methods =
        access.control.allow.origin =
        bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
        header.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter
        internal.key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
        internal.value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
        key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
        listeners = null
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        offset.flush.interval.ms = 60000
        offset.flush.timeout.ms = 5000
        offset.storage.file.filename =
        offset.storage.partitions = null
        offset.storage.replication.factor = null
        offset.storage.topic =
        plugin.path = null
        rest.advertised.host.name = null
        rest.advertised.listener = null
        rest.advertised.port = null
        rest.host.name = null
        rest.port = 8083
        ssl.client.auth = none
        task.shutdown.graceful.timeout.ms = 5000
        value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

[2020-01-18 18:16:53,628]  INFO {org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverterConfig} - JsonConverterConfig values:
        converter.type = key
        schemas.cache.size = 1000
        schemas.enable = true

[2020-01-18 18:16:53,628]  INFO {org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverterConfig} - JsonConverterConfig values:
        converter.type = value
        schemas.cache.size = 1000
        schemas.enable = false

[2020-01-18 18:16:53,628]  INFO {io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine$EmbeddedConfig} - EmbeddedConfig values:
        access.control.allow.methods =
        access.control.allow.origin =
        bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
        header.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter
        internal.key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
        internal.value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
        key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
        listeners = null
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        offset.flush.interval.ms = 60000
        offset.flush.timeout.ms = 5000
        offset.storage.file.filename =
        offset.storage.partitions = null
        offset.storage.replication.factor = null
        offset.storage.topic =
        plugin.path = null
        rest.advertised.host.name = null
        rest.advertised.listener = null
        rest.advertised.port = null
        rest.host.name = null
        rest.port = 8083
        ssl.client.auth = none
        task.shutdown.graceful.timeout.ms = 5000
        value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

[2020-01-18 18:16:54,209]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} - Starting MySqlConnectorTask with configuration:
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,209]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    connector.class = io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,209]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.history.file.filename = C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2\STREAM~1\446521~1.0\bin\..\cdc\history\TotalSweetProductionApp\InputStreamB.dat
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,225]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.history.file.filename = C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2\STREAM~1\446521~1.0\bin\..\cdc\history\TotalSweetProductionApp\InputStreamA.dat
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,225]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.user = root
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,225]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.user = root
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,225]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    offset.storage = org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.cdc.source.listening.InMemoryOffsetBackingStore
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,225]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    offset.storage = org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.cdc.source.listening.InMemoryOffsetBackingStore
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,225]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.server.name = localhost_3306
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,225]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.server.name = localhost_3306
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,225]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.port = 3306
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,225]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.port = 3306
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,225]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    table.whitelist = productiona.SweetProduction
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,225]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    table.whitelist = productionB.SweetProduction
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,225]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    cdc.source.object = 544973929
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,225]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    cdc.source.object = 1707012215
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,225]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.hostname = localhost
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,240]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.hostname = localhost
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,240]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.password = ********
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,240]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.password = ********
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,240]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    name = TotalSweetProductionAppInputStreamB
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,240]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    name = TotalSweetProductionAppInputStreamA
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,240]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    server.id = 6017
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,240]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    server.id = 5748
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,256]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.history = io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory
[2020-01-18 18:16:54,256]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask} -    database.history = io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,693]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask} - Found no existing offset, so preparing to perform a snapshot
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,693]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask} - Found no existing offset, so preparing to perform a snapshot
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,818]  INFO {io.debezium.util.Threads} - Requested thread factory for connector MySqlConnector, id = localhost_3306 named = binlog-client
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,818]  INFO {io.debezium.util.Threads} - Requested thread factory for connector MySqlConnector, id = localhost_3306 named = binlog-client
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,849]  WARN {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - Error while register the MBean 'debezium.mysql:type=connector-metrics,context=snapshot,server=localhost_3306': debezium.mysql:type=connector-metrics,context=snapshot,server=localhost_3306
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,849]  INFO {io.debezium.util.Threads} - Requested thread factory for connector MySqlConnector, id = localhost_3306 named = snapshot
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,849]  WARN {io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader} - Error while register the MBean 'debezium.mysql:type=connector-metrics,context=binlog,server=localhost_3306': debezium.mysql:type=connector-metrics,context=binlog,server=localhost_3306
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,849]  INFO {io.debezium.util.Threads} - Creating thread debezium-mysqlconnector-localhost_3306-snapshot
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,849]  INFO {io.debezium.util.Threads} - Requested thread factory for connector MySqlConnector, id = localhost_3306 named = snapshot
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,849]  INFO {io.debezium.util.Threads} - Creating thread debezium-mysqlconnector-localhost_3306-snapshot
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,865]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - Starting snapshot for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?useInformationSchema=true&nullCatalogMeansCurrent=false&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull with user 'root' with locking mode 'minimal'
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,865]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - Starting snapshot for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?useInformationSchema=true&nullCatalogMeansCurrent=false&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull with user 'root' with locking mode 'minimal'
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,881]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - Snapshot is using user 'root' with these MySQL grants:
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,881]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - Snapshot is using user 'root' with these MySQL grants:
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,881]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,881]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,881]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,881]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,896]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - MySQL server variables related to change data capture:
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,896]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - MySQL server variables related to change data capture:
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,896]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  binlog_annotate_row_events                    = ON
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,896]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  binlog_cache_size                             = 32768
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,912]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  binlog_checksum                               = CRC32
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,912]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  binlog_annotate_row_events                    = ON
[2020-01-18 18:16:55,912]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  binlog_commit_wait_count                      = 0
.....

[2020-01-18 18:16:55,912]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  binlog_cache_size                             
io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  collation_server                              = utf8mb4_general_ci
.....



[2020-01-18 18:16:57,616]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -   'performance_schema.events_statements_history_long' is filtered out, discarding
.......

[2020-01-18 18:16:58,395]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  snapshot continuing with database(s): [phpmyadmin, test, productionb, productiona, shipmentdb]
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,395]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  snapshot continuing with database(s): [phpmyadmin, test, productionb, productiona, shipmentdb]
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,411]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - Step 6: generating DROP and CREATE statements to reflect current database schemas:
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,411]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - Step 6: generating DROP and CREATE statements to reflect current database schemas:
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,442]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  SET character_set_server=utf8mb4, collation_server=utf8mb4_general_ci;
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,442]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  SET character_set_server=utf8mb4, collation_server=utf8mb4_general_ci;
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,507]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `productiona`.`sweetproduction`
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,507]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `productionb`.`sweetproduction`
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,519]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `productionb`
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,519]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `productiona`
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,519]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  CREATE DATABASE `productiona`
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,519]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  CREATE DATABASE `productionb`
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,535]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  USE `productionb`
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,535]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  USE `productiona`
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,566]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  CREATE TABLE `sweetproduction` (
  `batchNo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `item` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`batchNo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,566]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} -  CREATE TABLE `sweetproduction` (
  `batchNo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `item` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`batchNo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,613]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - Step 7: committing transaction
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,613]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - Step 7: committing transaction
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,613]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - Step 8: releasing global read lock to enable MySQL writes
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,613]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - Step 8: releasing global read lock to enable MySQL writes
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,613]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - Writes to MySQL tables prevented for a total of 00:00:02.5
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,613]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - Writes to MySQL tables prevented for a total of 00:00:02.5
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,628] ERROR {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - Failed due to error: Aborting snapshot due to error when last running 'UNLOCK TABLES': com/mysql/jdbc/CharsetMapping org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: com/mysql/jdbc/CharsetMapping
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.wrap(AbstractReader.java:200)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.failed(AbstractReader.java:178)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader.execute(SnapshotReader.java:709)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/CharsetMapping
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlValueConverters.charsetFor(MySqlValueConverters.java:304)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlValueConverters.converter(MySqlValueConverters.java:272)
        at io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder.createValueConverterFor(TableSchemaBuilder.java:331)
        at io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder.convertersForColumns(TableSchemaBuilder.java:254)
        at io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder.createKeyGenerator(TableSchemaBuilder.java:143)
        at io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder.create(TableSchemaBuilder.java:122)
        at io.debezium.relational.RelationalDatabaseSchema.buildAndRegisterSchema(RelationalDatabaseSchema.java:112)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlSchema.lambda$applyDdl$3(MySqlSchema.java:361)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlSchema.applyDdl(MySqlSchema.java:355)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader.lambda$execute$12(SnapshotReader.java:441)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.query(JdbcConnection.java:412)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.query(JdbcConnection.java:353)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader.execute(SnapshotReader.java:439)
        ... 3 more

[2020-01-18 18:16:58,628] ERROR {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - Failed due to error: Aborting snapshot due to error when last running 'UNLOCK TABLES': com/mysql/jdbc/CharsetMapping org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: com/mysql/jdbc/CharsetMapping
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.wrap(AbstractReader.java:200)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.failed(AbstractReader.java:178)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader.execute(SnapshotReader.java:709)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/CharsetMapping
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlValueConverters.charsetFor(MySqlValueConverters.java:304)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlValueConverters.converter(MySqlValueConverters.java:272)
        at io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder.createValueConverterFor(TableSchemaBuilder.java:331)
        at io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder.convertersForColumns(TableSchemaBuilder.java:254)
        at io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder.createKeyGenerator(TableSchemaBuilder.java:143)
        at io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder.create(TableSchemaBuilder.java:122)
        at io.debezium.relational.RelationalDatabaseSchema.buildAndRegisterSchema(RelationalDatabaseSchema.java:112)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlSchema.lambda$applyDdl$3(MySqlSchema.java:361)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlSchema.applyDdl(MySqlSchema.java:355)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader.lambda$execute$12(SnapshotReader.java:441)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.query(JdbcConnection.java:412)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.query(JdbcConnection.java:353)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader.execute(SnapshotReader.java:439)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.CharsetMapping cannot be found by siddhi-io-cdc_1.0.10
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:398)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:361)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:353)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 17 more

[2020-01-18 18:16:58,847]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask} - Stopping MySQL connector task
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,847]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask} - Stopping MySQL connector task
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,847]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.ChainedReader} - Stopping the snapshot reader
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,847]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.ChainedReader} - Stopping the snapshot reader
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,847]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask} - Connector task finished all work and is now shutdown
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,847]  INFO {io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask} - Connector task finished all work and is now shutdown
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,863] ERROR {io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader} - Unable to unregister the MBean 'debezium.mysql:type=connector-metrics,context=snapshot,server=localhost_3306'
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,878] ERROR {io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader} - Unable to unregister the MBean 'debezium.mysql:type=connector-metrics,context=binlog,server=localhost_3306'
[2020-01-18 18:16:58,863] ERROR {org.wso2.siddhi.core.stream.input.source.Source} - Error on 'TotalSweetProductionApp'. Connection to the database lost. Error while connecting at Source 'cdc' at 'InputStreamA'. Will retry in '5 sec'. org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.ConnectionUnavailableException: Connection to the database lost.
        at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.cdc.source.CDCSource.lambda$connect$0(CDCSource.java:400)
        at io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine.run(EmbeddedEngine.java:793)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: com/mysql/jdbc/CharsetMapping
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.wrap(AbstractReader.java:200)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.failed(AbstractReader.java:178)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader.execute(SnapshotReader.java:709)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/CharsetMapping
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlValueConverters.charsetFor(MySqlValueConverters.java:304)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlValueConverters.converter(MySqlValueConverters.java:272)
        at io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder.createValueConverterFor(TableSchemaBuilder.java:331)
        at io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder.convertersForColumns(TableSchemaBuilder.java:254)
        at io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder.createKeyGenerator(TableSchemaBuilder.java:143)
        at io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder.create(TableSchemaBuilder.java:122)
        at io.debezium.relational.RelationalDatabaseSchema.buildAndRegisterSchema(RelationalDatabaseSchema.java:112)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlSchema.lambda$applyDdl$3(MySqlSchema.java:361)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlSchema.applyDdl(MySqlSchema.java:355)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader.lambda$execute$12(SnapshotReader.java:441)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.query(JdbcConnection.java:412)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.query(JdbcConnection.java:353)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader.execute(SnapshotReader.java:439)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.CharsetMapping cannot be found by siddhi-io-cdc_1.0.10
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:398)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:361)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:353)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 17 more
```

In lib folder of Stream Processor default libraries exist plus my new jar files:

- mysql-connector-java-8.0.19
- postgresql-42.2.9
- siddhi-io-cdc-1.0.10

Mysql is run over XAMP v3.2.4 and mysql version is (by select verion query): 10.4.11-MariaDB-log

Could anyone help please? Is there maybe a problem in Java driver or CDC integration jar file?

Comment: user3682508, have you been able to solve the issue ? I am getting the exact same issue. And not sure what is @Niveathika mentioned "debezium depended on jars in the pack"  I have mysql-connector in the lib and siddhi-io-cdc is already available

Answer (score 0):

CDC Listening mode uses Debezium to get data, You need to have debezium depended on jars in the pack. Follow prerequisites  https://github.com/siddhi-io/siddhi-io-cdc